# cpanel - I'd like to add CNAME for domain.com

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record

I want to change an `A` record of my root domain `www.domain.com` to `CNAME dyndns.org`.

But the cpanel gives me the following error:

```
already has a SOA record.
You may not mix CNAME records with other records for the same name.
```

Can you please explain what this means? And how do I fix it?

Comment: are you kidding me? why the down vote? some people just enjoy down-voting without writing a single word?

Comment: @MadHatter how can it be duplicate of something asked two years after? :) if you want the other question is duplicate of this.

Comment: The other is a **canonical** question.  Look around SF; once we have a canonical question on a given subject, it is normal to close all other occurrences of that question as duplicates.  Note, however, that all closers other than me closed this because it's cpanel-related, and most web-panel-admin questions are (now) also OT here.

Comment: @MadHatter do as you please, I'm banned from here anyways :) necromancy goes the long way though.

Comment: @MadHatter that doesn't have sense. It a good question. It's a new way to ask probably something more canonical, but I think that a place like this is to resolve life to people not to show how much they know. **A question like this maximize alternatives to find a solutions**.
Probably a better alternative should be an edition de top answer with a link to canonical "question" with a canonical "answers" . This help a lot to know 'what is the must to be known' to solve in any web-panel-admin. It's not bad a cpanel related post, because it could help to solved fast for cpanel-related users.

Comment: @molavec do feel free to add to the canonical answers, or propose a new question on [meta](https://meta.serverfault.com/) (don't just create one out of the blue, though, that tends not to go well).  But you should also be aware that cpanel questions (like all webpanel not-really-sysadmin questions) have [a high bar to exceed](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/3425/55514) on SF.  And, of course, a `CNAME` is absolutely prohibited at the root of a zone, and no amount of flannel about "*maximising alternatives to find a solution*" will get around that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just to clarify, `www.example.com` is not the root of the domain, `example.com` is.

A `CNAME` on `www.example.com` is valid, but a `CNAME` on `example.com` is not - cpanel is right to reject the attempt.  A `CNAME` record can only exist on a name when no other record type exists for that name, since it indicates that all lookups (of any type, not just `A`) for that name should look up against a different name instead.  You must always have at a minimum an `SOA` record and an `NS` record on your root name (`example.com`), so a `CNAME` conflicts with the existence of those records.

Comment: to overcome this problem, can I CNAME www.example.com to dyndns server, and in some way redirect example.com to www.example.com ?

Comment: @SandroDzneladze Yes, but that depends on having a mechanism to perform the redirect.  Do you have a web server available that can be pointed at through an `A` record, which can then redirect to the `www` name?

Comment: yes I have hostgator account where I'm setting up cname records to point to my homeserver with dynamic IP. What would be google safe way of redirecting example.com to www.example.com?

Comment: @SandroDzneladze A 301 redirect is the search friendly way to do that; it informs the search engine that the redirect is "permanent".